# Managing Groups in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

In `iReport` I have a groupheader below the column header. Is there any way I can move the group header above the column header?

Answer (score 2):

You could move the column headers into the group header below the existing group headers.  Or you can also create a second group header for the same group below the first one, and add the column headers there.  To do this in iReport, right-click on the group header in Report Inspector and select "Add Another Group Header Band".  By setting the "Reprint Header" property to true, you can have these headers appear on each page.

Answer (score 1):

No I do not believe so, sorry.

Comment: The groupheader adds empty cells after the data. Is there any way I can get rid of that?.

Comment: Minimize the height of the groupingheader to where the fields fit perfectly in there.